# Shell script, saving the command value to a variable

Tags: linux, shell, echo

I am trying to print the value of `VARI` in the same line followed by a comma, so that i can have a csv file of these values, but i m not able to save the value of 
 `VARI = 'cat filename | head -1 | cut -d, -f${i}'`

```
i=0
while (( i<130)) ;
do
  if [[ $i -eq 1 ||  $i -eq 9 || $i -eq 12 || $i -eq 23 || $i -eq 25 || $i -eq 29 ]]
  then
    VARI = 'cat filename | head -1 | cut -d, -f${i}'
    echo  "$VARI ,"   
  fi
  let i=$i+1;
done
```

output expected is

```
4,abc,5,8,xyz,9
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong, thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to put back quote.  But In `VARI` the line should have back quote

Comment: @badawi -- tried it, does not work..first.sh: line 8: VARI = cat filename | head -1 | cut -d, -f${i}: command not found

Comment: @badawi: `VARI = \`cat filename | head -1 | cut -d, -f${i}\`` :)

Comment: @knittl: how did you do that?

Comment: first.sh: line 8: VARI: command not found.. am i missing something?

Comment: Sorry i just want to rewrite it but i don't know how to put back quote.  There is no space around `=`. i.e. `VARI=\`cat filename | head -1 | cut -d, -f${i}\``

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use backticks (or `$()` which can be nested), not single quotes:

```
VARI=`cat filename | head -1 | cut -d, -f${i}` # or:
VARI=$(cat filename | head -1 | cut -d, -f${i})
```

Make sure to not have spaces between the variable name, the equal sign, and the variable value.

```
VAR = x # executes program "VAR" with 2 parameters: "=" and "x"
VAR =x  # executes program "VAR" with a single parameter: "=x"
VAR= x  # executes program "x" with environment variable "VAR" set to an empty value
VAR=x   # assigns value "x" to shell variable "VAR"
```

Resources: [2.10.2 Shell Grammar Rules](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02) of the POSIX.1-2017 specification.

Comment: first.sh: line 8: VARI: command not found.. am i missing something?

Comment: Awesome.. thanks! .. works!.. such silly mistake!.. did not realise the importance of space ;)